# Alter display name string from "First M. Last" to "Last, First M."?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a name "John B. Smith", I need to change the format of the name to "Smith, John B."  I was thinking about using a regex, but I don't fully understand it even after reading about it.  Can someone help?

Also can you take a moment to explain what is going on in the expression?

Comment: Step #1 Try something #2 Observe what happened #3 Update/correct and repeat or proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example I've put up at [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/74woHSK2Dt).

The regex I used is `(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)`.  Here is a break down of it:

1. When I use `\w+`, I am saying that I'm looking for a regex with one or more letters, numbers or underscores.  This is commonly used to look for words.
2. When I use `\s+`, I'm looking for one or more space characters.
3. The `()` means that I want to capture (aka remember) the portion of the input that this regex matched.

Answer (score 1):

Regex may be overkill for parsing something simple like names, compared to parsing email addresses or HTTP addresses that regular expressions are commonly used for.

Why not just split the name by the space character and then create a new string with the 3rd array element (Smith) - with a comma inserted - before the first (John).

Comment: so somethinglike                                                                                                                          name.split("\\s") System.out.println ("nameArray[1] + "," + nameArray[0]